# Verifying if a real non-symmetric matrix has at least one eigenvalue with positive real part

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ is a real non-symmetrix square matrix and we know there exists a real vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $x^T A x > 0$. Can we conclude that $A$ has at least one eigenvalue with a positive real part? If not, what is a sufficient condition to show $A$ has at least one eigenvalue with a positive real part?

An easy $d=2$ case is $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $x = [1,0]^T$, where the two eigenvalues of $A$ are 2 and 1.

Comment: Show your attempts for $d=2.$

Comment: Any square matrix be decomposed into the sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric matrices. With the quadratic form, one term will vanish and you will end up with a symmetric matrix. For positive definite matrix, as a matter of fact, all  eigenvalues are nonzero positive real values.

Comment: Thanks, that I understand, $A_1 = (A+A^T)/2$ and $A_2 = (A-A^T)/2$, and $x^T A x = x^T A_1 x > 0$. But how can we conclude that $A$ has at least one eigenvalue with a positive real part from this decomposition?

Comment: Expand the expression and you will notice one term will disappear. Finally, rewrite the quadratic form using new variables $x=Py$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this point, could you please specify how I should expand the expression and what are $P$ and $y$?

Comment: $x^T (A_1+A_2) x =x^T A_1 x+x^TA_2 x$.

Comment: Notice that any symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable.

Comment: So $A_1 = P D P^{-1}$, and I did understand that $x^T A_2 x = 0$ since $A_2$ is antisymmetric. But I'm sorry that I still don't get why this leads to the conclusion that $A$ has at least one eigenvalue with a positive real part.

Comment: Let $x=Py$ and change $x^TAx$ to the new variable and expand the new quadratic form. What do you notice?

Comment: Also, $A_1=PDP^T$.

Comment: When I replace it and expand the quadratic expression, I get $y^T P^T A_1 P y + y^T P^T A_2 P y = y^T P^T A_1 P y > 0$.

Comment: What is $P^TA_1P$?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, so $P^T A_1 P = P^T P D P^T P = D$, and $x^T A x = y^T D y > 0$

Comment: But I'm still not getting the final steps from $y^T D y > 0$ to $A$ having an eigenvalue with a positive real part.

Comment: @KunJin, the eigenvalues of symmetric matrices are always real not complex. There is no point of saying positive real part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one off diagonal entry of the matrix is positive and dominating we can achieve $x^TAx>0$ for $x=(1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ no matter what eigenvalues are.

Let $$A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 10 \\ 0 &- 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ For $x=(1,1)^T$ we have $$x^TAx=-2+10-1=7 $$ The eigenvalues are negative and the matrix is non symmetric.

If we replace the assumption by $x^TAx>0$ for every nonzero vector $x$ then the conclusion holds. Indeed for every vector $e_k$ from the standard basis we have $$a_{kk}=e_k^TAe_k>0$$ Hence ${\rm Tr}A>0.$ on the other hand the trace is equal the sum of all the eigenvalues. Therefore at least one eigenvalue has positive real part.

Comment: your answer is not clear.

Comment: @CroCo On the contrary. It is a clear counter example imho

Comment: @RaoulLuqué we are not after a single case(i.e. $x=(1,1)^T)$. We want to answer the question for all $x$.

Comment: @CroCo OP assumes "there exists". So I have sticked to that assumption.  The question "for all" is different and the answer is different. I have re-edited to capture that case.

Comment: I agree this is a clear counter-example and helps me understand the first part of my question, thank you. 

I'm still curious about the second part of the question: "what is a sufficient condition to show  has at least one eigenvalue with a positive real part?" given that we do not have to solve for the eigenvector. 

For example, if $A$ has other types of diagonal dominance, will we have a different conclusion?

Comment: As you can see from my extended answer it suffices that $x^TAx>0$ for $d$ orthogonal nonzero vectors.There is no need to determine any eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

Any square matrix can be decomposed into the sum of a symmetric and a skew-symmetric matrices. For the quadratic form, one term will disappear, resulting in a symmetric matrix; therefore, if the matrix is not symmetric, it is safe to assume so.

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $A=A^T$. Any symmetric matrix is orthogonally diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are real. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the quadratic form $f(x) = x^TAx $ is positive definite if and only if $f(x)>0$ for all $x\neq 0$. We know $A=PDP^T$ where $D$ a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are the eigenvalues of A. Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x=Py$ where $P$ is an invertible matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$; therefore, we get
$$
\begin{align}
f(y) = x^TAx &= (Py)^TA(Py) \\
&= y^TP^TAPy \\
&= y^T Dy \\
&= y^T \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1&  & \\& \ddots& \\ &&\lambda_n\end{bmatrix}y \\
&= \lambda_1y^2_1+\lambda_2y^2_2+\cdots+\lambda_ny^2_n.
\end{align}
$$

The function $f(y)>0$ for all $y\neq 0$ is completely determined by the signs of the eigenvalues.

Comment: For a nonsymmetric matrix $A$ there is no direct connection between its eigenvalues and the eigenvalues of $(A+A^T)/2.$